# GraceNote - generate playlist with music of a given country

Tags: gracenote

I would like to use GraceNote to generate play-lists which contain songs likely to appeal to, or, at least, be known to, residents of a given country. E.G, Japan, Korea, Turkey, Brazil, France ...

They don't necessarily have to be in the local language, as I don't think that I can do that with GraceNote (can I ?), but local artists would be nice. Is there any way, for instance, to query and generate a playlist using `artist origin`?

I realize that something like Gangnam Style might be known in most countries ;-) and that play-list generation is inexact when used this way, but I would be happy with a 70 or 80% "I know that song" reaction.

Can it be done? If so, how?  @cweichen, can you help?

Comment: You should specify which Gracenote product you are referring to but in this case I do not think what you ask can be supported by any product. Actually the question it self maybe highly debatable as I think there would only be a handful of songs that would be familiar to 70~80% of the users in a given country. People have different taste and preferences and I don't think you can generate a big playlist that will be familiar to most of the users.

Comment: Another alternative may be to use popular album charts in the given country.

Comment: I am current coding in Python & using Pygn (https://github.com/cweichen/pygn), so it's the Gracenote music API, but I will use anything.  The 70-80% was just an example (probably a bad one), my app is just for testing something else and I want a list where "many or most (t.b.d)" of the tracks are from a given country and/or in a given language. As to "use popular album charts in the given country", I am restricted to using Gracenote. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @alan, you might as well post that as an answer. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, @Mawg. I have re-posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems likely you are referring the the Rhythm API. As you probably can see from the function definition, you cannot create a playlist using 'ARTIST_ORIGIN'.

The closest thing I can think of is creating a playlist (aka radio station) using on a popular song in the given country as a seed.

You may try configuring the 'focus_similarity' value to get a wider variety of songs. This is just a suggestion and I am not sure if this will get you what your looking for.

*Pygn currently does not support 'focus_similarity' configuration but it should not be too difficult to add yourself.